# Python: filtrar dataframe con condiciones especificas de las filas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buenas tardes comunidad

tengo el siguiente problema

tengo un DF cuya primera columna tiene el periodo ej (202101, 202102, 202103), por cada periodo tengo asociados los datos de una persona con un código de identificación, requiero eliminar los periodos mas antiguos si el código ha cambiado en una determinada cantidad de meses, el *df* original se ve así:

| periodo | cod | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 738 | Paula |
| 202102 | 738 | Paula |
| 202103 | 738 | Paula |
| 202101 | 124 | sandra |
| 202102 | 124 | sandra |
| 202103 | 124 | sandra |
| 202101 | 124 | Yeison |
| 202102 | 738 | Yeison |
| 202103 | 738 | Yeison |
| 202101 | 123 | Carlos |
| 202102 | 123 | Carlos |
| 202103 | 432 | Carlos |

Como se observa por cada periodo `paula`, `sandra`, `yeison` y `carlos` tienen un `cod` asociado, sin embargo, `yeison` en el periodo 202101 tenia un código y para el resto de periodos (202102 y 202103) un código diferente, lo que significa que cambio, para Carlos paso lo siguiente: en el periodo 202101 y 202102 tenia un código y para el periodo 202103 cambio.

Requiero que se elimine el o los registros diferentes de los periodos mas antiguos y siempre se mantenga el del periodo o los periodos  mas nuevos cuando un código cambie; para el resto de información deberá mantenerse el periodo y el código si no ha existido ningún cambio, el resultado final debería ser:

| periodo | cod | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 738 | Paula |
| 202102 | 738 | Paula |
| 202103 | 738 | Paula |
| 202101 | 124 | sandra |
| 202102 | 124 | sandra |
| 202103 | 124 | sandra |
| 202102 | 738 | Yeison |
| 202103 | 738 | Yeison |
| 202103 | 432 | Carlos |

Esto me sucede un en DF con mas de 1000 registros con nombres y codigos diferentes no me pasa solo para una persona en especifico, es por esto que no puedo filtrar por una persona debo hacer que el codigo recorra el DF valide si tiene un codigo diferente y elimine los periodos antiguos quesandose con el o los periodos mas recientes que tengan el mismo codigo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow , te recomiendo que realices el [tour] y leas [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta y te podamos apoyar

Comment: No hacemos los trabajos de nadie, lo sentimos, para ello debes haber realizado algo y así poder recibir ayuda de algo que no te salga o no vaya.

Comment: @Christian sabemos que es una pregunta que no cumple con las recomendaciones para ser buena pero ten en cuenta que es un usuario nuevo y en vez de solicitar el cierre hay que asesorar para que logre editar o realizar una pregunta de calidad.

Comment: @MRDev hace aprox. 1 hora que el usuario publicó la pregunta y pese a los comentarios aun no la ha editado. En caso edite su respuesta retiro mi voto, por ahora esta pregunta no encaja en el sitio. En caso de ser cerrada igual existe la opción para reabrir la pregunta

Comment: me disculpo soy muy nuevo en el tema intentare revisar y re ordenar, apuesto aque alguna vez fueron nuevos asi que aprecio los comentarios positivos al respecto y el respeto por quienes aun no tenemos un gran nivel de conocimiento, saludos

Comment: @HaroldBarrantes edita tu pregunta con los que has intentado (cual quier esfuerzo que hayas tenido) y te ayudaré, si no tienes la más mínima idea avisamé y te explicaré todo a detalle en mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución puede ser realizar un agrupamiento por nombre, después usar el método [`last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html?highlight=last) para obtener la última fila de cada grupo, que según entiendo en tu problema, la última fila de cada nombre tiene el periodo mas reciente. Posteriormente seleccionamos solo las columnas `nombre` y `cod`.

```
df_select = df.groupby('nombre').last().reset_index()[['nombre', 'cod']]
```

`df_select` lucirá entonces así:

|  | nombre | cod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Carlos | 432 |
| 1 | Paula | 738 |
| 2 | Yeison | 738 |
| 3 | sandra | 124 |

Luego, simplemente utilizamos [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge) para hacer un *`inner-join`* entre `df_select` y tu dataframe original `df`, por las claves `nombre` y `cod`

```
df = pd.merge(df, df_select, on=['nombre', 'cod'])
print(df)
```

Output:

|  | periodo | cod | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 202101 | 738 | Paula |
| 1 | 202102 | 738 | Paula |
| 2 | 202103 | 738 | Paula |
| 3 | 202101 | 124 | sandra |
| 4 | 202102 | 124 | sandra |
| 5 | 202103 | 124 | sandra |
| 6 | 202102 | 738 | Yeison |
| 7 | 202103 | 738 | Yeison |
| 8 | 202103 | 432 | Carlos |

Comment: Creo que una solución más simple hubiera sido ordenar el df y borrar los duplicados

Comment: Claro! usando `keep='last'`

Comment: Exactamente, esa era mi solución pero el OP no se interesó por mejorar la pregunta así que no le di una respuesta, igual tu respuesta es buena